# How to check if a Bootstrap UI modal is open? - AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-ui

My application can open a modal if there's already one open. If that's the case I want to close that modal and open the new one after that's done.

Service to open modals:

```
app.service('ModalService', function($uibModal) {
this.open = function(size, template, content, backdrop, controller) {
    var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
        animation: true,
        templateUrl: content,
        windowTemplateUrl: template,
        controller: controller,
        backdrop: backdrop,
        size: size,
        resolve: {}
    });
    return modalInstance;
};
```

Then I open one with:

```
var m = ModalService.open('lg', '', 'ng-templates/modal.html', true, 'ModalController');
```

And I can close it with:

```
m.close();
```

I can only use m.close() within the same switch/case as I open the modal. If I want to close it in another if statement later in the code m is undefined.

Anyway. Can I check if a modal is open? If I console.log(m) then there's this:

```
d.$$state.status = 1
d.$$state.value = true
```

But I cannot access the variable m elsewhere in my app so I cannot check for that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just add an flag or getter to your `ModalService`.

```
app.service('ModalService', function($uibModal) {
var open = false,
    modalInstance;

this.isOpen = function () {
  return open;
};

this.close = function (result) {
  modalInstance.close(result);
};

this.dismiss = function (reason) {
  modalInstance.dismiss(reason);
};

this.open = function(size, template, content, backdrop, controller) {
    var modal = $uibModal.open({
        animation: true,
        templateUrl: content,
        windowTemplateUrl: template,
        controller: controller,
        backdrop: backdrop,
        size: size,
        resolve: {}
    });

    //Set open
    open = true;

    //Set modalInstance
    modalInstance = modal;

    //Modal is closed/resolved/dismissed
    modal.result.finally(function () {
      open = false;
    });

    return modal;
};
}
```

You can then call: `ModalService.isOpen()` to check if your modal is opened.

Comment: Pretty neat, will give it a shot and report back. Thanks.

Comment: This works. Any idea how I can close the modal? I've now replaced var m with $rootScope.m which allows me to access m everywhere in my app.

Wondering if there's a better solution.

$rootScope.m = ModalService.open('lg', '', 'ng-templates/modal.html', true, 'ModalController');

Then I do: $rootScope.m.close();

Comment: Just store the `modalInstance` like `open` as a local variable and implement an additional function (for example: `ModalService.closeModal()`) and close the modal inside your service.
The question is why you want to close the modal from outside its scope.

Comment: I might need to close it from another controller or in another if statement. Using a var doesn't work but $rootScope.variable does.

Comment: I've made an edit and added `ModalService.dismiss(reason)` and `ModalService.close(result)` methods. I left the checking if `modalInstance` is set, you should add it before using it in your code.

Answer (score 2):

## Very easy:

Since `$uibModal` always uses a div with class name `modal` you can just check if any element with that class name exist:

```
//If no modal is open
if (document.getElementsByClassName("modal").length === 0) {
  //do something...
} else {
  // do something when a modal is open
}
```

Comment: hmm thats dirty check, not really the best soln, especially if you have multiple modal opens at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

Since the $uibModal service doesn't provide it, the leanest way is to check for "modal-open" class on the body:

```
document.body.className.indexOf('modal-open') !== -1
```

Comment: Really the easiest way ! Thank you very much